# Devolver array mas aproximado

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy realizando un proyecto y me gustaría implementar una funcionalidad parecida a un match en tinder.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
let arrayOne = ["Bueno con otros animales", "Bueno con otros perros", "Bueno con los coches"]

let arrayTwo = personality.value
```

`Personality.value` es un valor que recupero de Firebase y que contiene 8 arrays con las diferentes características de un animal. Muestro un ejemplo:

```
0: (4) ['Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno con niños', 'Bueno en casa', 'Cariñoso']
1: (4) ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Cariñoso', 'A veces ladro', 'Amigable con extraños']
2: (5) ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno en el coche', 'Cariñoso', 'Amigable con extraños']
3: (4) ['Me gusta pasear', 'Me gusta estar en compañía', 'Cariñoso','Juguetón']
4: (4) ['Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno con niños', 'Bueno en casa', 'Cariñoso']
5: (3) ['Bueno con gatos', 'Timido', 'Juguetón']
6: (5) ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno con otros animales', 'Me gusta pasear', 'Cariñoso']
7: (4) ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Bueno con niños', 'Cariñoso', 'Bueno en casa']
8: (3) ['Cauteloso con extraños', 'Tímido', 'Independiente']
```

Quiero comparar el `arrayOne` con los diferentes arrays de `arrayTwo` y sacar el array que contenga más coincidencias.

He probado el siguiente codigo pero no me devuelve nada:

```
function calc() {
  const arr = model.value;

  const arr1 = personality.value;

  const arr_ = [arr1];

  const matches = arr_.filter((array) => {
    let posibles = arr.length * -1;

    // Si el tamaño es 2, tendremos -2. Al final acabará en 0.
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == array[i]) {
          posibles++;
        }
      }
    }
    return posibles ? false : true;
  });

  console.log(matches); // [ Array(3), Array(4)]
}
```

Gracias

Comment: `8 arrays con las diferentes características de un animal`, agrega eso tambien para que te peudan ayudar con mayor efectividad, agrega tambien un [example], me refiero, que has intentado? que errores tienes hasta el momento. Stackoverflow no es un lugar donde escribas quiero hacer esto  y te hacen el trabajo/tarea, lee [tour] y [ask]

Comment: disculpa @David081, he realizado los cambios oportunos para dar mas informacion.

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto mi solución. Podrías apoyarte de variables auxiliares, como en el siguiente código:

```js
let arrayOne = ["Bueno con otros animales", "Bueno con otros perros", "Bueno con los coches"];
let arrayTwo = [
  ['Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno con niños', 'Bueno en casa', 'Cariñoso'],
  ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Cariñoso', 'A veces ladro', 'Amigable con extraños'],
  ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno en el coche', 'Cariñoso', 'Amigable con extraños'],
  ['Me gusta pasear', 'Me gusta estar en compañía', 'Cariñoso', 'Juguetón'],
  ['Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno con niños', 'Bueno en casa', 'Cariñoso'],
  ['Bueno con gatos', 'Timido', 'Juguetón'],
  ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Bueno con gatos', 'Bueno con otros animales', 'Me gusta pasear', 'Cariñoso'],
  ['Bueno con otros perros', 'Bueno con niños', 'Cariñoso', 'Bueno en casa'],
  ['Cauteloso con extraños', 'Tímido', 'Independiente']
];

function calc() {
  let coincidencias = []; // inicializo un array donde se almacenarán las coincidencias
  let aux1 = 0; // inicializo una variable auxiliar

  arrayTwo.forEach(arr2 => { // recorro el segundo array
    let aux2 = 0; // inicializo una segunda variable auxiliar
    arrayOne.forEach(arr1 => { // recorro al primer array
      if (arr2.includes(arr1)) { // valido que si un elemento del arr2 coincide con arr1...
        aux2++; // incremento en uno a aux2
      }
    });

    // aux2 solo incrementa cuando encuentra coincidencias, y en este if ingresan los que son mayores a "aux1", entonces...
    // valido que si aux2 (incrementado por la cantidad de coincidencias) es mayor al aux1 (que es 0)...
    if (aux2 > aux1) {
      aux1 = aux2; // aux1 será aux2 (es decir, en cada recorrido, aux1 será modificada por la cantidad de coincidencias de aux2, así hasta que llegue el momento que no entre al if).
      coincidencias = arr2; // y el subarray de "arrayTwo" (arr2) que entre al if, lo igualo al array "coincidencias" (esto puede cambiar, dependiendo a quien tenga más coincidencias).
    }
  });
  return coincidencias;
}

console.log(calc(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto: [Código](https://zhenglinlei.github.io/paste-code/#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)

```js
function calc(arr, arr1) {
    let match = [];


    // Foreach and return nearest array
    arr1.forEach((el, i) => {
        if (el.some(r=> arr.indexOf(r) >= 0)) match.push([i, el]);
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript
        //
        // ES2016: arr1.some(r=> arr2.includes(r))
    });

    return match;
  
}

console.log(calc(model.value, personality.value));
// Return an array with [[id, element], ...];
```

Comment: No se porque el foreach no le gusta. Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')"

Comment: Me podría pasar el raw del `personality.value`? Igual `personality.value` no es un array.

Comment: Aqui tienes la info:

Proxy {0: Array(4), 1: Array(4), 2: Array(5), 3: Array(4), 4: Array(4), 5: Array(3), 6: Array(5), 7: Array(4), 8: Array(3)}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(9)
[[IsRevoked]]: false

Comment: También prueba a ver usando `console.log(typeof personality.value);` para conocer si es un Objeto tipo Object o Array

Comment: Y si no, prueba hacer un `console.log(JSON.stringify(personality.value);` para obtener el string del objeto que te devuelve Firebase

Comment: personality.value is a Object. Entiendo que por eso no funciona el foreach, no?

Comment: Si es un object. Usa `Object.values(personality.value)` para obtener el array de los valores solo.